# Cant seem to draw linear regression in the same graph as scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have been trying to plot a linear regression line on my scatterplot but the graphs seem to push my scatterplot down. The scatterplot seem fine without the regression line. Please see image 1.

But once i run `ax.plot(X,Y_pred,color= 'red')` the graph gets distorted. I have checked the values they all seem fine. Im just confused why this happens. Please help thank you.

Image 1[image]

Image 2 - With regression line
[image]

```
    #for regression line
X = latest_data1.iloc[:,3].values.reshape(-1,1)
Y= latest_data1.iloc[:,4].values.reshape(-1,1)
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X,Y)
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(latest_data1['residential_land_area'],latest_data1['dwelling_units_under_management'])
ax.plot(X,Y_pred,color= 'red')
plt.title("Number of units vs Residential Land area in 2018 (Density)", fontsize=18, y=1.03)
plt.xlabel('Residential land area (hectares)')
plt.ylabel('Dwelling units')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: can  you print Y_pred ?

Comment: Do X = latest_data1['residential_land_area'].values and Y = latest_data1['dwelling_units_under_management'].values

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The values from Y_pred is okay.  Ranges from 26000 to 78000.

Comment: I followed the 2nd comment but i get this error: Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: check latest_data1['residential_land_area'] and X values

Comment: Hi Pygirl thank you for the prompt replies. I realised the data of latest_data1['residential_land_area']  was obj. the problem resolve once i change it to float. thank you for the help!!